# ionic android platform build failing

Tags: android, cordova, build, ionic-framework

i'm trying to build my ionic app to android using win 10 and it keeps failing..

heres the error message

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
>
>   > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   >     'C:\Users\gadi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe''
>   >     finished with non-zero exit value 1
>
> Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args:
>   /s,/c,"c:\dev\ionic\SmartCall\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug
>   -b c:\dev\ionic\SmartCall\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"

and these are the versions i'm using (`ionic info`)

```
> Cordova CLI: 6.0.0 
> Gulp version: CLI version 1.2.1 
> Gulp local: Ionic
> Version: 1.2.4-nightly-1917
> Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.14
> Ionic App Lib
> Version: 0.7.0 
> OS: Node Version: v5.7.0
```

any ideas?

EDIT:

I tried to make a blank project and build it and it worked just fine, 
but when I add my www folder the fails.. so it must be something with my code :/

i installed libraries using bower and like i said when using `ionic serve` it works fine - no console errors.

what can be wrong with my code?

Comment: try building from terminal

Comment: i am building from terminal... 'ionic build'

Comment: There could be a filename error in your assets folder. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38173333/ionic-android-build-fails-cordovalibprocessdebugresources/38175575#38175575